# Best strategy for storing timed data and plotting afterwards?

Tags: python, bash, datetime, plot, storing-data

I'm trying to learn Python by converting a crude bash script of mine. 
It runs every 5 minutes, and basically does the the following:

1. Loops line-by-line through a *.csv* file, grabs first element (**$URL**),
2. Fetches **$URL** with wget and extracts **$price** from the page,
3. Adds **$price** to the end of the same line in the *.csv* file,
4. Continues looping for the remaining lines.

I use it to keep track of products prices on eBay and similar websites. It notifies me when a lower price is found and plots graphs with the product's price history.

It's simple enough that I could just replicate the algorithm in Python, however, as I'm trying to learn it, it seems there are several types of objects (lists, dicts, etc.) that could do the storing much more efficiently. My plan is using *pickle* or even a simple DB solution (like *dataset*) from the beggining, instead of messing around with *.csv* files and extracting the data via sketchy string manipulations.

One of the improvements I would also like to make is store the absolute time of each fetch alongside its price, so I can plot a "true timed" graph, instead of assuming each cycle is 5 minutes away from each other (which it never is).

---

*Therefore, my question sums to...*

Assuming I need to work with the following data structure:

- List of Products, each with its respective

  - **URL**
  - And its list of **Time<->Prices pairs**

**What would be the best strategy in Python for doing it so?**
*Should I use dictionaries, lists, sets or maybe even creating a custom class for products?*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you plan on accessing the data structure which holds the URL-(time,Price) for specific URLs - use dictionary, since URLs are unique (the URL will be the key in the dictionary).

Otherwise u can keep a list of (URL,(time,Price)) tuples.

Secondly, a list of (Time, Price) Tuples since you don't need to sort them (they will be sorted already by the way you insert them).

{} - Dictionary
[] - List
() - tuple
Option 1:
[(URL, [(time, Price)])]

Option 2:
{URL, [(time, Price)]}